# Updating FitNesse using Fitsharp, FitVersionFixture. IsStandard not working

Tags: .net, fitnesse, fitsharp

I have a question concerning an error I am receiving. I am working on updating my system and FitNesse to .Net 4.0. I am using FitSharp in order to do so. When running through my tests however to check if the update is working properly I am coming across an error that I'm not sure how to fix.

I am using: FitVersionFixture.IsStandard

However, now with .Net 4.0 and FitSharp, I am getting the following error:

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean fit.FitVersionFixture.get_IsStandard()

It appears that the method has been deprecated. I have been unable to figure out how to go about fixing this problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the 'Behavior' section on http://fitsharp.github.com/FitSharp/SuiteConfigurationFile.html

Comment: If you want to check the setting use: Processor.Configuration.GetItem<Settings>().Behavior